# null valors when Insert Json POST into Mysql Php

Tags: php, arrays, json, pdo

I'm trying to sync my Android local database to my webservice, but I'm getting some problems inserting the JSON string into mysql, because all my values are null.
From Android I send the JSON string and this is what I get in Php.

```
  [{
        "prop_id": "1",
        "edo_sync": "No",
        "titulo": "Departamento en renta ",
        "actualizacion": "2016:10:25 19:14:33",
        "categoria": "Venta",
        "superficie": "30m2",
        "_id": "1",
        "propiedad": "Casa",
        "fecha": "10/25/16"
    }, {
        "prop_id": "1",
        "edo_sync": "No",
        "titulo": "Casa en renta",
        "actualizacion": "2016:10:27 13:30:08",
        "categoria": "Venta",
        "superficie": "100m2",
        "_id": "2",
        "propiedad": "Casa",
        "fecha": "10/25/16"
    }, etc...
    }]
```

this is my php file:

```
<?php
try
{
    include("constantes.php");
    //Recibimos Objeto Json
    $Propiedad = $_POST["PropiedadPost"];

    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        echo "activado";
    $Propiedad = stripslashes($Propiedad);


    //Decode JSON into an Array
    $data = json_decode($Propiedad );

    print_r ($data);

    $options  = array('uri' => URL_BASE,'location' => WEBSERVICE);
    $client   = new SoapClient(NULL, $options); 

    for($i=0; $i<count($data) ; $i++)
    {
    //Store prop into MySQL DB
        $response = $client->InsertarPropiedad($data[$i]);
        print_r ($data[$i]);
        echo $response;
    }   
}
    }catch(Exception  $e){
        echo "Error:".$e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

and here is my class to insert data.

```
public function InsertarPropiedad($CadenaJson) {
    $ObjetoJson = json_decode($CadenaJson);
    $response   = array("Msg"=>"","IdRegistro"=>"0"); 
    try
    { 
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO PROPIEDADES (prop_id,titulo,propiedad,categoria,superficie,fecha,actualizacion,edo_sync,_id) VALUES(:PROP_ID,:TITULO,:PROPIEDAD,:CATEGORIA,:SUPERFICIE,:FECHA,:ACTUALIZACION,:EDO_SYNC.:ID)");
        $stmt->bindparam(":PROP_ID",$ObjetoJson->prop_id);
        $stmt->bindparam(":TITULO",$ObjetoJson->titulo);
        $stmt->bindparam(":PROPIEDAD",$ObjetoJson->propiedad);
        $stmt->bindparam(":CATEGORIA",$ObjetoJson->categoria);
        $stmt->bindparam(":SUPERFICIE",$ObjetoJson->superficie);
        $stmt->bindparam(":FECHA",$ObjetoJson->fecha);
        $stmt->bindparam(":ACTUALIZACION",$ObjetoJson->actualizacion);
        $stmt->bindparam(":EDO_SYNC",$ObjetoJson->edo_sync);
        $stmt->bindparam(":ID",$ObjetoJson->_id);

        $stmt->execute();

        $response["Msg"] = "Propiedad Registrado Correctamente";
        $response["IdRegistro"] = $this->db->lastInsertId(); 
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        $response["Msg"]       = $e->getMessage();
        $response["IdRegistro"] = "0"; 
    }
    return json_encode($response);
}
```

the message i get:

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'prop_id' cannot be null"

Comment: Turn on PHP error reporting and you will see what's going on. This is, actually, the very purpose of the error reporting: to remind you to uncomment json_decode line

Comment: Even if uncomment json_decode still throws the same error.

Comment: then you have to turn on the error reporting and find out why the value is null

Comment: In my first php file Decode JSON into an Array
    $data = json_decode($Propiedad );
and then i do a **for** to send the array ... But then I don't know why the values are null

Comment: because you are accessing them wrong way. check your values BEFORE sending them to PDO

Comment: I added this line to my for..  
$encoding = json_encode($data[$i]);
$response = $client->InsertarPropiedad($encoding);

and it works